# Entropy of Poisson random variable via exponential family identity

Tags: probability, entropy, exponential-family

Exercise 8.1 of Probabilistic Graphical Models asks the reader to use the identity
$$H_{P_{\theta}}(X)= \ln Z(\theta) - \langle E_{P_{\theta}}[\tau(X)], t(\theta)\rangle$$
to compute the entropy $H$ of a random variable with distribution $P_\theta$ parameterized by $\theta$. This assumes the distribution is in exponential family form so that $P_{\theta}(X) = \frac{1}{Z(\theta)}A(X)\exp(\langle \tau(X), t(\theta)\rangle)$ where $\tau$ and $t$ denote functions for calculating the sufficient statistics and natural parameters.

For a Poisson RV, $t(\theta)=\ln \theta$ and $t(X)=X$ so we have $H=\theta(1- \ln \theta)$ and this is indeed the first term of the listed expression for the [Poisson entropy on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) but is clearly wrong since $H\ge0$ and the parameter space for $\theta$ allows values that would lead to negative entropy for the above expression.

I feel that I am missing something very basic but I can't determine my mistake. Has anyone come across this problem before?

Comment: I do not understand the initial identity since $\mathbb E[\log A(X)]$ is missing there (and not in the Wikipedia result). Unless this is another definition of entropy.

Comment: The initial identity does appear to be mistaken; an earlier portion of the text gives a definition of linear exponential family members as distributions satisfying $P_{\theta}(x)=\frac{1}{Z(\theta)} \exp \{\langle \theta, \tau(x)\rangle\}$ which omits the term $A(x)$ which I believe is a mistake since there the accepted definition of this class appears to allow for $A(x)\ne 1 $ (i.e. https://doi.org/10.1017/S0305004100043097). Once the correction for the expectation of $\log A(X)$ is included, then everything makes sense. Thanks!